# Saving read-only data in Sqlite for Android outside activity context

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I need to have a read only database for an android application with three simple tables:

1. Countries
2. Cities ( country_id foreign key)
3. PhoneCountryCodes (country_id foreign key)

I have .csv files that I need to extract data from and fill in these tables. The purpose for these tables is for the android app reading purposes and data validation.

The link [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html) shows how to add data to the managed database Sqlite for android. Yet it seems from the following code that I need a Context to instantiate the DbHelper class:

```
FeedReaderDbHelper mDbHelper = new FeedReaderDbHelper(getContext());
```

In other words, I want to add data to the database once and for all (basically Country data, cities and phone country codes), outside of the Activity context.

Answer (score 1):

use getApplicationContext(); If you don't want activity context.